# How to prevent specific bones in an ik rig to bend?

Tags: rigging, bones

So, i created an ik rig for my arm model and it looks good except for the forearm part. As seen in the picture below, the forearm consists out of three bones.[image]

But when i move the hand, the forearm bones bend, which i dont want.(picture below)[image]

how do i prevent them from bending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IK is calculated after all modifier stacks, every bone of an IK chain has a properties panel in which you can configure its behaviour.

[image]